# show line numbers for console statements in IE 9 debugger

Tags: javascript, console, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

I hope this is something simple..
I am using the F12 Development tool debugger in IE 9.  Is there a way I can display the line numbers and file source for each console statement, the same way that Firebug displays this info?  I may have overlooked something basic, but I haven't yet found a way to do this..Thanks!

Comment: no answers...is it possible IE has a debugger that doesn't give you line numbers of console statements? Is someone kidding me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get line numbers is to define a [window.onerror](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/better-error-handling-with-window-onerror/) method:

```
window.onerror = function (message, url, lineNo)
  {
  console.log('Error: ' + message + '\n' + 'Line Number: ' + lineNo);

  return true;
  }

console.log(window);
console.log(1=2);
```

But even then, IE breaks on the error, so it's rather useless.

Comment: Great! It also helps when debugging in older Android Stock Browser when using about:debug